# Locating cronjobs after exec-ing php script

Tags: php, cron

So I'm making some cronjobs for automating the execution of some scripts. I'm making the cronjobs using the following command:

```
exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\nmin hour day month year wget http://... | crontab -');
```

My question is where do these cronjobs get written to? I checked the crontab on my server and they were not there...are they being written as an anonymous user on my server?

Comment: Not quite to your question, but is there a reason you are programmatically creating cron jobs?  Why not have a script that gets ran periodically and downloads the URLs needed?

Comment: Good point. I might try changing the way i'm doing things currently, however for now i'm just curious on where these jobs are being stored.

Comment: where/how are you running this exec() from? it's under a webserver, then the cron job'll be created under the webserver's ID.

Comment: I'm running it off of my EC2 server. I checked both root and ec2-user crontab, but still nothing...is there a different user?